Sliding texture in U does not evenly cross wedge-shaped quad
I have a semi-circle mesh with quads arranged radially. (The inner-most edges are short, but non-zero length.) The UVs are designed so that textures sliding in U will rotate around the semi-circle, mirrored on both sides. It's almost working as intended.

However, if I hide the mesh, zoom in, and move slowly, you can see that as the blue portion of the texture crosses the inner quads, it does not interpolate perfectly radially:

This is not an optical illusion. Turning back on the wireframe, we can see that the blue is filling the width of the inner quad near the origin, but then is nowhere near the edge of that same quad near the outer edge, nor does the texture fill the quad in the outer ring:

I think the setup is clean:

The mesh was created by generating a mesh circle, extruding the outer edges without moving them (E Z 0 Enter) and then scaling them towards the origin (S 0.8 Enter). Repeat for the inner quads, scaling down to about 0.01. These should be radially perfect within the limits of high-precision floating point values.

The UVs are perfectly aligned in a grid, by selecting rows and columns of verts and scaling their offsets to 0 on the opposite axis (S X 0 Enter). Each column might have slightly varying widths, making them not quite perfectly distributed across the width, but they're pretty close, and the edges of each quad are definitely vertical in UV space.

The texture is (overkill, to be sure) a 512x512 grid of colors, as seen in the UV map above. The Texture is set to use Closest interpolation, but the same result occurs with Linear.

The texture is slid by animating the X coordination only of the UV Texture Coordinates. The same problem is seen if I go into the UV editor, and slide the UVs in X only (G X mouse slide).



Any suggestions for what's going on here, and how to fix it?
My next steps are going to be trying to subdivide the inner sectors, or try for triangles instead of quades on the inner sectors.

I don't understand why it's happening--I can only guess that it's something about the precision of the vertex coordinates--but the problem is directly tied to how small the central ring gets, how close the points are to each other:

Note in the above how the blue line starts parallel to the quad edge, but as the scale is shrunk it angles over and touches the edge. Once the vertices go past the origin (not desirable) that effect disappears, but other overlapping effects show up.
The solution, then, is simply to subdivide the interior ~sectors. The innermost sector still shows the problem, but the rest of them do not, which makes the problem almost imperceptible.


The root cause is described and shown in Possible to uniformly slide UV across non-rectangular quad?. That also shows that the problem DOES exist on the "interior sectors", it's just less obvious. Subdivision of the wedge-shaped quads in either direction helps mitigate the issue, but does not remove it perfectly.
